# Combine two different RDD's with two different sets of data but the same key

Tags: pyspark

RDD_1 contains rows like the following:

```
(u'id2875421', 2, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 24, 55), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 32, 30), 1, -73.9821548461914, 40.76793670654297, -73.96463012695312, 40.765602111816406, u'N', 455)
```

RDD_2 contains rows like the following:

```
(u'id2875421', 1.9505895451732258)
```

What I'm trying to do is get an rdd in the form of

```
(u'id2875421', 2, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 24, 55), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 32, 30), 1, 1.9505895451732258, u'N', 455)
```

So I'm trying to replace the location columns with a distance column.

rdd1.join(rdd2) gives me:

```
(u'id1585324', (1, 0.9773030754631484))
```

and rdd1.union(rdd2) gives me:

```
(u'id2875421', 2, datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 24, 55), datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 32, 30), 1, -73.9821548461914, 40.76793670654297, -73.96463012695312, 40.765602111816406, u'N', 455)
```

Comment: `rdd1.join(rdd2)`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what happens when I try to use join()

Comment: That example makes no sense. How do you get `'id1585324'` as the result of the join, when you started with `id2875421`? Please [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @pault I updated the question. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, just convert the first RDD into a paired RDD and then join:

```
rdd1.keyBy(lambda x: x[0]) \
    .join(rdd2) \
    .map(lambda x: x[1][0][:5] + (x[1][1],) + x[1][0][9:]) \
    .collect()

#[(u'id2875421',
#  2,
#  datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 24, 55),
#  datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 17, 32, 30),
#  1,
#  1.9505895451732258,
#  u'N',
#  455)]
```

Here I use the [keyBy()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.keyBy) function to convert x[0] of *rdd1* to key and the original element as value, then join *rdd2* and use map() function to pick what you want in the final tuple.